# Laurent series of $e^z$

Tags: complex-integration, laurent-series

find the Laurent series centered at $z=1$
$$
f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}
$$
I thought that the denominator part is safe by our center and the expansion is just about the exponential which is a Taylor series but that doesn't match the calculator solution. Any help is appreciated.

Solution:

so we are good at $(z-1)^2$, then we just need to do Taylor expansion for $e^z$ at $z=1$.( that's the center for our Laurent series), which would be
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}\sum \frac{e}{k!}(z-1)^k
$$
thanks for everyone making the hint!

Comment: What is your answer? Can you write it down.

Comment: updated. thought it naively but the calculator gave me something else.

Comment: Can you also post what did your calculator show?

Comment: Problem: your answer isn't a power series. You would need $\sum a_k z^k$ for a series centred at $0$, or $\sum a_k (z - 1)^k$ for a series centred at $1$ (the latter is what you want). Mixing both gives you neither. Try computing the Taylor series for $e^z$ at $z = 1$, instead of $z = 0$. Doing it naively by differentiation is not hard!

Comment: Hint: $$
f(z) = e\frac{{e^{z - 1} }}{{(z - 1)^2 }} = \frac{e}{{(z - 1)^2 }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty   \ldots  
$$

Comment: Why does your title say one thing and your body another?

Comment: @79999 You should indicate the limits of the summation.

Answer (score 3):

First notice that $z=1$ is a singularity of $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{(z-1)^{2}}$. Setting the change of variables $u=z-1$, we have $u+1=z$. Thus, rewriting all depending of $u$, we have
\begin{align*}\frac{e^{z}}{(z-1)^{2}}&=\frac{e^{u+1}}{u^{2}},\\&=\frac{e}{u^{2}}\cdot e^{u},\\&=\frac{e}{u^{2}}\left(1+u+\frac{u^{2}}{2!}+\frac{u^{3}}{3!}+\cdots\right),\quad |u|<+\infty \\ &=\frac{e}{u^{2}}+\frac{e}{u}+\frac{e}{2!}+\frac{e}{3!}u+\cdots,\\&=\frac{e}{(z-1)^{2}}+\frac{e}{z-1}+\frac{e}{2!}+\frac{e}{3!}(z-1)+\cdots\end{align*}
with $z=1$ a pole of order $2$ and the series converges for all $z\not=1$.

Therefore the Laurent Series around of the singularity $z=1$ is given by
\begin{align*}\frac{e^{z}}{(z-1)^{2}}&=\frac{e}{(z-1)^{2}}+\frac{e}{z-1}+\frac{e}{2!}+\frac{e}{3!}(z-1)+\cdots,\\&=\sum_{n=-2}^{+\infty}\frac{e}{(2+n)!}(z-1)^{n}\end{align*}
with convergence for all complex $z$ *except* $z=1$.

Comment: is that $(z-1)^n$ instead not 2?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I fixed it, thank you